# git repo with svn external/submodule

Tags: git, svn, version-control, external, git-submodules

I have been searching for a long time now.
And cannot really find a good enough answer for my problem.

We now use SVN for our projects. These projects share 3 libraries which are also SVN repos. 
We include them into our projects via SVN externals.

We are looking into GIT now and I am searching for a solution to use these libraries and keep them synced between GIT and SVN.

I tried using submodules, but they only support GIT repos, not SVN.
Then I created a new GIT repo for our library and used that as a submodule in our GIT project. Then I added a svn remote to the submodule, which allowed me to fetch from svn and commit to svn.

But then I ran into the problem where the new GIT library and SVN library went out of sync. someone committed to SVN and i comitted to GIT and all hell broke loose. I cannot get them synced anymore. Merging and more stuff failed all over the place.
so the solution I came up with is not what I want. 
It generated more problems than solutions for us.

So, my question: What is the best solution to keep data synced?
Some relatively older projects need to keep the reference to their GIT or SVN revision(submodules do exactly what we want).

It is o.k. for us, for now, to keep de libraries in SVN only.
Can someone explain to me how this should/can be handled?

Thank you

Comment: I see no use (and I'm well experienced in this SVN/GIT issue) in partly switching to Git - either fully migrate to Git or migrate nothing. No good will come out of a SVN/GIT mix.

Comment: I know it is not easy, but we are not ready to migrate fully to git.

Comment: The current status seems worse than not using GIT or switching to GIT. You'll get those issues again and again.

Comment: It certainly feels like that right now. But is there something we can do on the server side? Can we keep a GIT and a SVN repo synced there?

Comment: The sync is safe mostly if it is one-directional (SVN2GIT or GIT2SVN) - a bi-direction sync causes many problems